# sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: "by"

Tags: python, pandas

So i have this dataset that goes like this

```
df2=df1.head(10)

genres  imdb_score
0   Action  6.239896
1   Adventure   6.441170
2   Animation   6.576033
3   Biography   7.150171
4   Comedy  6.195246
5   Crime   6.564792
6   Documentary 7.180165
7   Drama   6.763763
8   Family  6.245055
9   Fantasy 6.307049
```

i wanted to make a bar graph so i did this

```
df3 = df2.sort_values()
df3.plot.barh()
```

but the result is

> TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

however if i draw the graph without sort_values() it worked fine like this

[image]

in addition anyone knows how to remove that little "imdb_score" writing on the top right of my bar graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is `DataFrame`, use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
print (df2.sort_values(by='imdb_score'))
        genres  imdb_score
4       Comedy    6.195246
0       Action    6.239896
8       Family    6.245055
9      Fantasy    6.307049
1    Adventure    6.441170
5        Crime    6.564792
2    Animation    6.576033
7        Drama    6.763763
3    Biography    7.150171
6  Documentary    7.180165
```

Then plotting by [`DataFrame.plot.barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html):

```
df3 = df2.sort_values(by='imdb_score')

ax = df3.plot.barh(x='genres', y='imdb_score')
#for remove label of y
ax.set_ylabel(None)
```

If sorting `Series`, by is omitted, because [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html).

```
print (df2.set_index('genres')['imdb_score'].sort_values())
genres
Comedy         6.195246
Action         6.239896
Family         6.245055
Fantasy        6.307049
Adventure      6.441170
Crime          6.564792
Animation      6.576033
Drama          6.763763
Biography      7.150171
Documentary    7.180165
Name: imdb_score, dtype: float64
```

Then plotting by [`Series.plot.barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.barh.html):

```
s3 = df2.set_index('genres')['imdb_score'].sort_values()
s3.plot.barh()
```

Comment: thanks so much again for your help. Is there any way to delete that little 'imdb_score' text on the top right of the graph?

Comment: @CarloSilanu -  What solution was used? First or second one?

Comment: I used the first one

Comment: @CarloSilanu - answer was edited. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61169502/revisions)